# I want to create an additional feature(column) based on some manipulation of values from existing features

Tags: feature-engineering, feature-construction

Consider my data-frame to be like this ('x','y','z' are features):

[image]

I want to create a **python function** which will take an expression as a string (something like this: 'x+y-2z') and create a new feature by evaluating the expression. Output should be like:

[image]

I want to generalize this function so that it will work for different data-frames with different column(feature) names in the expression.

Edit- I have a prototype of the desired function(named 'parser'):

def parser(exp):

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.x+row.y-2*row.z, axis=1)
```

However, I want to generalize this part - **row.x+row.y-2*row.z** so that it will adjust itself according to the string(i.e. expression) provided as its argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community!

The code below is a starter. You can go on by naming the column and adding it to the original DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[10,20,30],'z':[100,200,300]})
print(data)
def my_fun(data,expression,variables):
    for v in variables:
        expression = expression.replace(v,'data.'+str(v))
    return eval(expression)


my_fun(data,'2*x+y',['x','y'])
```

output

```
   x   y    z
0  1  10  100
1  2  20  200
2  3  30  300

0    12
1    24
2    36
dtype: int64
```

There are two ways in general:

1. Use *eval* function to evaluate/execute expression in string form as I did.
2. Use symbolic libraries, most commonly used is [SymPy](https://maths-with-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07-sympy.html), to use symbolics directly as variables.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!